# Windows XP on Hyper-V Server - broke view after change resulution

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hyper-v

I have a computer with Windows XP installed.

The goal is to move this workstation to the virtual machine.

I uninstalled the disk driver and used Disk2VHD.

I am trying to run a virtual machine with this disk image on a server with Hyper-V Server installed.

I connect to Hyper-V Server using a computer with Windows 10 and Hyper-V Manager.

At first the mouse does not work.

I am using the keyboard to install Hyper-V Guest Component from hyper-v2008r2-vmguest.iso or hyper-v2008-vmguest.iso or vmguest.iso or hyper-v2012r2-vmguest.iso file.

While installing hyper-v guest I am seeing a lot of notifications like these:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXHTx.png

I see the message "installation complete" from hyper-v guest installer. I do reboot the VM.

The mouse starts working.

I have a resolution of 640x480.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmjFm.png

I change the Windows settings to 1024x768.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NixXf.png

The view broke.

I drew the yellow color in the picture for anonymous purpose.

What can I do to make it normally with a resolution higher than 640x480?

Comment: Did you install a display driver?

Comment: What monitor / driver do you mean considering it's a virtual machine?

Comment: If you want more then the basic display functionality of Windows you have to provide a virtual display adapter or expose physical hardware to the VM. Running dxdiag will probably answer most of your questions.

Comment: I have a resolution of 1920x1080 on my Windows 10 virtual machine. Why can't I have it on Windows XP (virtual machine)? On the same hardware.

Comment: What can I do to make it normally with a resolution higher than 640x480?

Comment: Install a display driver. Hyper-V might not have a virtual display driver that supports Windows XP. Which is the reason I ask if you had installed one. Windows 10 supported a higher resolution due to that virtual display adapter driver being installed

Comment: You say: "Install a display driver.". Ok. Please give me a link to driver. I will install.

Comment: Consider a more friendly VM App (VMware) and consider installing XP from an XP CD (eBay) to help eliminate driver issues.  I have an XP VM that I built from CD.

Comment: I cant' built from CD because this system was use from 15 years and configure it from screatch is work for many many months.

Comment: Try a different VM app and then now you know why backups are needed. XP can be set up in a single day.

Comment: What version of Hyper-V Server?  Is the XP VM gen 1?  Is XP updated to SP2? I know that XP SP2 will work and all the drivers you need are installed when the integration components (IC) are installed.  Also, please try the 2012 version of the IC.  https://smudj.wordpress.com/2017/03/02/vmguest-iso-for-older-windows-oses-in-win102016/